# error in Selenium UI tests with Internet explorer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, selenium-iedriver

Hi I am running some UI selenium tests that connect to Browserstack for each run. I am getting some sort of session error and I do not know how to resolve this. see error and config below:

i have just added config for IE as below:

testng xml file

```
  <test name="Test - Internet Explorer">
        <parameter name="browser" value="IE"/>
        <parameter name="browserVersion" value="11.0"/>
        <parameter name="os" value="Windows"/>
        <parameter name="osVersion" value="10"/>
        <parameter name="resolution" value="1024x768"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.bookinggo.ticketed.uiendtoend.TicketedSingleJourneyTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

capabilities

```
  @BeforeMethod (alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters({"browser", "browserVersion", "os", "osVersion", "resolution"})
public void setUp(String browser, String browserVersion, String os, String osVersion, String resolution)
        throws Exception {
    capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_NETWORK_CONNECTION, "true");
    capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
    capability.setCapability("browser", browser);
    capability.setCapability("browser_version", browserVersion);
    capability.setCapability("os", os);
    capability.setCapability("os_version", osVersion);
    capability.setCapability("resolution", resolution);
    capability.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");
    capability.setCapability("browserstack.localIdentifier", "Test123");
    capability.setCapability("project", "Ticketed Transport");
    capability.setCapability("build", "Selenium Ticketed End To End UI Tests");
    capability.setCapability("name", "Ticketed book flow journey");
    capability.setCapability("browserstack.networkLogs", "true");
    capability.setCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", "true");
    URL = new URL(URL_STRING);
    setupScreenshot();
}
```

i am getting this error just for IE, with Chrome and Firefox there is no issue:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Command not found: GET /session/7624397802b5dced4edafe3032da36ea577ecb91/local_storage/key/sessionState
    Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
    System info: host: 'C02XW09XJHD5', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1049:76ca:412a:58dc%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '11.0.2'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    Capabilities {browserAttachTimeout: 0, browserName: internet explorer, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enableElementCacheCleanup: true, enablePersistentHover: true, handlesAlerts: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ie.usePerProcessProxy: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: about:blank, javascriptEnabled: true, nativeEvents: true, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, requireWindowFocus: false, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: dismiss, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss, version: 11, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 7624397802b5dced4edafe3032d...}
    Session ID: 7624397802b5dced4edafe3032da36ea577ecb91
```

any idea what is wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put value not browser name not "IE" , but: "Internet Explorer"